# c# vscode Newtonsoft.Json not working, error CS0246

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

When trying to compile my code I ran into this problem which does not make any sense to me. It tells me that the namespace I'm trying to reference could not be found, although it clearly should be. I tried restarting vscode, restoring the project, building a completely new project(shown below), and adding the package name to the dependencies, but this is the error I get every time:

```
c:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Projects\c#\request\Program.cs(2,7): error CS0246:  The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)



using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace request
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Is that *definitely* the project file associated with the code? What happens if you run "dotnet build" from the directory containing the code and the project file? It looks like it should be fine. (As a side note, I'd strongly recommend following .NET naming conventions for your namespace.)

Comment: I tested this case with `dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json`, changed Program with `using Newtonsoft.Json;` and then `dotnet run`,  no issues. BR

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for helping! Using this[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSdEl.png) vs code extension seems to be root of the problem. When I execute the code using any of these[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyX8P.png) buttons it gives me this error(twice, for some reason)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m8Jd.png).

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! was taring my hair out trying to find out what was wrong with a client's build and found this answer. Turns out they had that extension and were using those added buttons to run their code.

Comment: so the solution is I should remove CS script extension from visual studio?